# React Native - Can't clickTouchableOpacity inside ImageBackground

Tags: image, react-native, rotation

I want create a rotate icon inside a image:

```
<ImageBackground style={stylesNative2.image} source={{ uri }} >   
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => { alert("handler here") }} tyle={styles.rotateImageIcon}>
    <Icon name='rotate-ccw' type='Feather' style={styles.rotateImageIcon} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</ImageBackground>

const stylesNative2 = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    zIndex: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    height: h,
    width: WIDTH,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    transform: [{ rotate: this.state.imageRotation + 'deg' }]
  }
});

const styles = StylesManager.getStyles({
  rotateImageButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    elevation: 0,
    zIndex: 1
  },
  rotateImageIcon: {
    marginTop: '1rem',
    marginLeft: '1rem',
    fontSize: '1.7rem',
    color: 'white',
  }
});
```

The icon appear but the TouchableOpacity is not working.
Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: can you share an expo link for the same? so i can check and revert?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `ImageBackgroud` have a `pointerEvent` like this one:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#pointerevents

Can you try to wrap your `<TouchableOpacity>` on a `<View>`?

Answer (score 0):

Mayby it's the zIndex...
A touchable opacity is transparent so you don't have to add zIndex on it.

Answer (score 0):

When we add TouchableOpacity inside the ImageBackground .
We need to add the zindex greater than ImageBackground.
like `zindex:100`
Elements with a higher index will be placed on top of elements with a lower index. **Note: Z** index only works on positioned elements ( position:absolute , position:relative , or position: fixed